# How to change the secondary DNS server entries on a network device via cmd?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-xp, windows-command-prompt

In Windows XP, how do you change the secondary DNS server on a network adapter via the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IN Windows XP, in order to change the secondary DNS server, you have to add it via cmd

```
netsh interface ip add dns
```

If a secondary DNS server already exists, it must first be removed before adding the new one. Again in cmd

```
netsh interface ip delete dns "[connection name]" [old DNS ip address]
```

replace [connection name] with the name of the network adapter (i.e. "Local Area Connection")
replace [old DNS ip address] with the I.P. address for the secondary DNS server to remove

To add the secondary DNS setting, use the following command:

```
netsh interface ip add dns "[connection name]" [ip for secondary DNS] INDEX=2
```

replace [connection name] with the name of the network adapter (i.e. "Local Area Connection")
replace [ip for secondary DNS] with the I.P. address for the secondary DNS server

Note that you can use an alternative method when you only need to change the primary DNS that is faster

```
netsh interface ip set dns "[connection name]" static [ip for primary DNS]
```

Comment: That will *insert* the DNS server at the given index, moving an existing entry to index 3. To *change* the secondary server you have to remove the existing entry before adding the new one: `netsh int ip delete dns "[connection name]" [old ip]`. And you can use the exact same syntax for changing the primary DNS server. Just set `index=1`.

Comment: I never noticed that. Adding it to answer. Thanks.

Comment: INDEX=2 is not valid parameter in windows xp